# using defined char in a case of switch

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

I used a predefined char variable in a case in my switch and got this error `case label does not reduce to an integer`

```
char player = 'X';
  switch(.....){
    case player:
.
.
.
.
```

I need a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [C11 standard](http://%20The%20expression%20of%20each%20case%20label%20shall%20be%20an%20integer%20constant%20expression):

> The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression

`player` is *not* a "*constant expression*".

Please note that in C qualifying a variable as `const`, does **not** make it a "*constant expression*" in the sense of the C standard.

A label either need to be an integer literal, or a `enum`, which in fact *is* an integer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
char player = 'X';
switch(player){
    case 'X':
    case 'Y':
    case 'Z':
```

(A char is an encoding and the encoding is an int)

Comment: `player` changes sometimes i need to use `player`

Comment: Then you code al possible values of `player`. See my update.